# UWP (c#): Main Loop (Event loop)

Tags: c#, loops, bluetooth, uwp

*Background:*
I'm relatively new to C# and UWP and started developing an app in order to learn the basics. I tried searching for an answer of what I assume to be a really basic question, but I wasn't able to find one (probably my fault).

So, the app I'm making is connected to a bluetooth device which streams some data.

The first "view page" is the bluetooth device selection and then it switchs to the main one where I'm going to do everything else. I got event handlers to deal with the incoming streamed data and process/store it.

However I would like to have a "main loop" running which will make some needed manipulations over the data. That being said, I don't really know how to do such a thing.

One way I thought about doing it, is to have a method like the one below, which is called from the class constructor. But I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it.

```
async void MainLoop()
{
     while (true)
     {
         //do stuff
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(X));
     }
 }
```

Comment: *"I would like to have a 'main loop' running which will make some needed manipulations over the data"* - Why isn't that code called in event handler you set up for reading available data? I cannot think of a valid reason, why you would want to structure the code in the way you explain. For one, there's an `X` in there, and that's a question you'll have to answer. Whenever you find yourself coming up with a good value, chances are, that you have opted for the wrong solution (as is in this case; no matter what, you will have to pick an **arbitrary** value).

Comment: I get your point and, in fact, you are right. My thought process was that since the bluetooth device is sending data from multiple sources (which might have different rates) that the best way would be to have a 'main loop' who would work at a specified frequency and use the latest data at the moment. However, as you said, I could just use one of the event handlers and apply the same principle!
The only thing I was afraid (and this might be due to my inexperience) is that the loop would get too large and affect the frequency at which I'm receiving/storing data

Comment: You have plenty of CPU power at your disposal. Don't fall into the trap of applying pre-mature optimization, just because something feels like it's a lot of work. Implement a solution to your problem. If it turns out, that it's too slow, **measure**, using a profiler, and only then implement an appropriate optimization. Measuring is important so that you know, whether your optimization produced the desired effect. From an architectural point of view, you might want to split responsibilities: Have the event handler only pick up the packets, and place them in a queue for later processing.